# postgresql 9.3: can't connect with password

Tags: postgresql

Created a user testdb1. Issued:

```
postgres=# alter user testdb1 with password 'testdb1';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=#
```

Then added an entry to pg_hba.conf:

```
local    all             testdb1         password (also tried md5)
```

but when I try to connect:

```
psql -U testdb1 -W
Password for user testdb1: (type in password here)
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "testdb1"
```

What am I still missing?

Answer (score 1):

The line I added:

```
local    all             testdb1         md5
```

need to be BEFORE the pre-existing line:

```
local   all             all               peer
```